# Как подружить Python и C++ | Python to bin/exe

Tags: python, c++

Здравствуйте еще раз.

Стоит задача переписать существующие классы/структуры данных в Python на C.
Слабо пока себе представляю, как это должно работать, но задача поставлена, необходимо изучить. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сие должно выглядеть? Желательно реальный опыт ибо ссылки не всегда спасают. А главное, насколько это ускорит выполнение программного кода?

Альтернативой данному виду маразма своих начальников вижу компиляцию Python в исполняемое приложение (linux-binary, windows-exe). Что думаете по этому вопросу?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, у начальников очередной маразм, отмели эту идею пока. Все ответы бы помогли, если бы я сам все выбирал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если стоит задача ускорить исполнение, то можно выявить узкие места профайлером и переписать эти места с помощью C extensions, получится, что будет работать тот же код, но быстрее. Подробнее тут [Extending Python with C or C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html)

Answer (score 3):

Классическая компиляция в исполнимый бинарник мало поможет, так как там просто берут и вклеивают интерпретатор.
Но есть такая приблуда - [PyPy](http://pypy.org/). Умеет компилировать в С код. Поэтому, генерим С код, смотрим на производительность, потом пробуем дошлифовывать профайлером.

Но есть ещё один путь. В питоне, что бы получить хорошую производительность в большинстве случаев достаточно побольше использовать стандартные либы, а не пытаться переписать стандартные алгоритмы на питоне ручками. Может производительности и хватит.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите в сторону [Cython](http://cython.org/).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Cython абсолютно является ответом на вопрос "Как подружить Python и С++"

Answer (score 1):

cython решение вашей проблемы.
Универсальное и исчерпывающее. )